# What Does "Turn On Notifications" mean on someone else's Facebook post?

Tags: facebook

Recently I was scrolling through someone's Facebook page (this person is NOT a Facebook friend of mine). I bumped the little ^ on one of this person's life events and it gave me a choice to click "I don't like this" or to click "Turn On Notification". I'm dying of curiosity to know: What happens if I click to turn on notifications in this instance? Would I start getting notifications of this person's posts or life events, even though they're not friends with me? What is that option about, in this case?

Answer (score 4):

It means that if someone likes that ***particular*** life event, or comments on it, you will get a notification.